# Learning C#, wrote faulty program, need help as to why it's not function how I want it to

Tags: c#, console, console.writeline, console.readline

I'm new to coding and wrote this little console reading program to try and make sense of arrays, methods, etc.
I know my code is very faulty and probably not properly written (by book).
I would like some help on how to fix my program though, it has an issue where the console lets me input a number but it doesn't read from my choices method. 
Any help would be greatly valued.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PalacioGameImproved
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WelcomeMessage();
        choices();

    }


    public static string WelcomeMessage()
    {
        string writeLines;
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a DooWop");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,15}", "0 = Johnny");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,13}", "1 = Nick");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,15}", "2 = Conrad");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,14}", "3 = Diane");
        Console.WriteLine("{0,13}", "4 = Rick");
        writeLines = Console.ReadLine();
        return writeLines;
    }

    public static void choices()
    {


        string[] names = new string[5];
        names[0] = "Johnny";
        names[1] = "Nick";
        names[2] = "Conrad";
        names[3] = "Diane";
        names[4] = "Rick";

        string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (UserInput == "0")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("is it the array");
        }

        else if (UserInput == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(names[1]);
        }

        else if (UserInput == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(names[2]);
        }

        else if (UserInput == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(names[3]);
        }

        else if (UserInput == "4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(names[4]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That was not one of the choices, please try again.");
            WelcomeMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean doesn't read from my choices method? choices() seem work properly to me. What is `writeLines` for?

Comment: The writeLines was set to return a string from Console.ReadLine, because without it I got an error about not all code paths returning a value.

Comment: Please do not deface you post, you can ask SE for removal of your user from this question, other users have spent time to answer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use Console.ReadLine 2 times. [.net Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0rmTnx) Your code should be

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       WelcomeMessage();
       choices();
    }

    public static void WelcomeMessage()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Pick a DooWop");
       Console.WriteLine("{0,15}", "0 = Johnny");
       Console.WriteLine("{0,13}", "1 = Nick");
       Console.WriteLine("{0,15}", "2 = Conrad");
       Console.WriteLine("{0,14}", "3 = Diane");
       Console.WriteLine("{0,13}", "4 = Rick");
   }

   public static void choices()
   {
      string[] names = new string[5];
      names[0] = "Johnny";
      names[1] = "Nick";
      names[2] = "Conrad";
      names[3] = "Diane";
      names[4] = "Rick";

      string UserInput = Console.ReadLine();

      if (UserInput == "0")
      {
         Console.WriteLine("is it the array");
      }

      else if (UserInput == "1")
      {
         Console.WriteLine(names[1]);
      }

      else if (UserInput == "2")
      {
         Console.WriteLine(names[2]);
      }

      else if (UserInput == "3")
      {
         Console.WriteLine(names[3]);
      }

      else if (UserInput == "4")
      {
          Console.WriteLine(names[4]);
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("That was not one of the choices, please try again.");
          WelcomeMessage();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any input you have on my code? Anything I need to be wary of in the future?

Comment: Check out the Code Review Stack Exchange site.